# Changing the icon of a console application vb.net

Tags: vb.net, icons, console-application

How to change the icon of a console application of vb.net? I changed the icon on project properties->Application->icon. But the old default icon remains..Any idea on how to do that please?

Comment: Have you tried Clean and Build again ?

Answer (score 1):

When i copied the exe to a new folder, the correct icon displayed. It could be a caching problem with explorer.exe then.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to recompile.  Clean the whole solution, then rebuild.